Tawk.to Widget Stops Working After Livewire Component Change in Laravel
I’m using Laravel Livewire with app.blade.php as the main layout for all pages. The app.blade.php file includes dynamic content using {{$slot}}. I’ve created a separate Livewire component for the Tawk.to widget (TawkWidget) and included it in the layout.
app.blade.php:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    @livewireStyles
</head>
<body>
    <livewire:header />
    {{ $slot }}
    <livewire:footer />
    <livewire:tawk-widget />
    @livewireScripts
</body>
</html>

tawk-widget.blade.php:
<div id="tawk-widget-container" wire:ignore>
    <!--Start of Tawk.to Script-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var Tawk_API = Tawk_API || {}, Tawk_LoadStart = new Date();
        (function () {
            var s1 = document.createElement("script"), s0 = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
            s1.async = true;
            s1.src = 'https://embed.tawk.to/id-provided/some-id';
            s1.charset = 'UTF-8';
            s1.setAttribute('crossorigin', '*');
            s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1, s0);
        })();
    </script>
    <!--End of Tawk.to Script-->
</div>

How I change component:
return cache()->remember('about-us-v10', 31536000, function () {
    return view('livewire.about-us')->layout('app')->render();
});

Issues:

On the initial page load, the Tawk.to widget works perfectly, and its  is injected into the DOM.
After switching Livewire components (updating the {{$slot}}), the widget disappears, and the  is not re-injected.

What I Tried:

Used wire:ignore in the widget component to prevent Livewire from interfering with the widget’s container.
Triggered reinitialization of the script on livewire:update and livewire:load events.
Moved the script directly into app.blade.php.
Tried @script and @endscript

Expected:
The Tawk.to widget should remain visible and functional across Livewire component changes, or it should reinitialize if needed.
How can I ensure the Tawk.to widget persists or reloads correctly after Livewire component changes? Any advice on handling third-party scripts with Livewire?
